# SlickGrid scrollCellIntoView doesn't scroll vertically

Tags: slickgrid

According to the SlickGrid documentation here:

https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#wiki-scrollCellIntoView

it sounds like the scrollCellIntoView method should scroll both horizontally and vertically if the column specified by the cell parameter is not currently in view. So if I have a grid with 200 rows and currently the first 50 rows are visible and column 7 is NOT visible, the following method call should scroll both horizontally and vertically to bring the cell at row 90, cell 7 into view.

```
mySlickGrid.scrollCellIntoView(90, 6);
```

However, it looks like this method only scrolls horizontally, putting the column into view but not the row.  Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating the behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/3hvye/3/

Does anyone know if this is the expected behavior, a bug, or perhaps I'm missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scrollCellIntoView` actually doesn't scroll the row at all.  Use it in conjunction with `scrollRowIntoView`.  This is an oversight and will be fixed.  (The reason that `scrollCellIntoView` takes in a `row` as an argument is that it is needed for colspan support.  Without it, SlickGrid wouldn't be able to uniquely identify the cell.)